# Quick REST server that answers with static responses?

Tags: windows, rest

Is there any program that could help me build a REST client without having access to the server? I just want to get custom static HTTP answers when accessing a specific url via POST. It should be as fast and easy as one of the many REST-clients for backend developers.

(No it's not because I develop the client before developing the server, it's because somebody else develops the server and I want to program even when neither this person nor his | her server is available.)

Platform: Windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you can serve static files, you can use any web server as a response generator.  Generate your data and save it in the file structure with an extension like .json or .xml.  I have found that this works for GET requests but is not very useful for POST/DELETE requests.  Sometimes a tool like fiddler http://fiddler2.com/ can let you capture the request while the server is live and then you have it when it goes offline.

If you want a more complex and true rest environment you can use mongoDB's http interface. http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/  A word of caution.  Mongo is a great tool but the learning curve is a little steep of you have not worked with NOSQL before.  The plus side is that it doesn't really require an application server since you hook your calls straight into the document structure via it's http console.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that later today or tomorrow.